# Generate new clauses in Prolog

Tags: prolog, task

I need to write a predicate where

```
`numberM` is `abs(2*numberS - 10) + 12`
```

There are clauses like

```
`s(numberS)` like `s(1), s(2)`
```

Please help me to write such a predicate

Answer (score 0):

So yo have these facts for `s/1`:

```
s(1).
s(2).
...
```

Now you can add a procedure `m/1` with this rule:

```
m(NumberM):-
  s(NumberS),  % Retrieve NumberS
  NumberM is abs(2*NumberS - 10) + 12.  % Compute your formula
```

Remember that prolog variables start with a capital letter.

Sample run:

```
?- m(NumberM).
NumberM = 20 ;
NumberM = 18.
```

Answer (score 0):

To add new facts like s(3), etc.

- By program: use the built-in predicate assertz/1. E.g. if you execute this program

  ```
  main :- assertz(s(3)).
  ```

you will get the fact s(3). and so on. In most prolog systems, you have to indicate that s/1 is a dynamic predicate that can be asserted/abolished or retracted by program, this is done by :- dynamic(s/1).

- At the prolog prompt you can type in

  ?- assertz(s(3)).

Or consult a file containing the facts.